# E/Trace(640): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: android

I installed Android SDK, JDK, Eclipse. My project name is Bible, and I build in eclipse Bible. In emulator this error shows *"Unfortunately, Bible has stopped"* and in Logcat this error message shows

```
E/Trace(640): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
shuttind down VM
```

How can I solve this?

**Update**: After a few minutes, in Logcat this message was added

```
com.example.bible Process Sending signal. PID: 623 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I suspect that the Trace error is just a red herring, and the real problem is somewhere else. Full logcat from the time of starting the app would be useful.

Comment: Sorry for a completely useless comment, but "Unfortunately, Bible has stopped" is now one of my top errors I have seen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2)

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you are asking" since it has been *years* without the asker being willing to provide the full logcat trace which would be needed to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

On my case i want to use "GridView", i have to enable the "GPU emulation". And this solve the problem.
From "AVD Manager" select the AVD u want to enable the "GPU emulation". Then click on "Edit". Finally on the "Hardware" section "New" then select "GPU emulation" from "Property", click on "OK".
Please note select to "Yes" from value under "GPU emulation" and press return of u r keyboard. Finally "Edit AVD".

Hope this will help, because this problem waste some of my hours.