# Hiding and Showing Tables in android

Tags: android, button, visibility, tablelayout, onclicklistener

I have created two tables, one on the left side and one in the center of the screen. When you start the application the table on the left is set to visible and the table in the center is set to invisible.

Now I want to click a button in the left table (Buton_left) and the entire table in the center would become visible.

I have this method so far but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information.

```
  package com.example.musicapp;
  import android.os.Bundle;

   public class Tbl_Show_Hide extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TableLayout table_left = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_left);
    TableLayout table_center = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_center);
    Button Buton_left = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Buton_left);

    table_left.setOnClickListener(this);
    table_center.setOnClickListener(this);
    Buton_left.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

    boolean visible = true;
    int targetId = v.getId();
    if(targetId == R.id.Buton_left)
    {
        if(visible)
                    {
        if(table_center.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
        {
            table_center.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        }

        }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [View#getVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility%28%29) may return one of [VISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE), [INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE), or [GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE). And you create table_center in onCreate method, that is a local variable, invisible to onClick.

So change it to:

```
public class Tbl_Show_Hide extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    final TableLayout table_left = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_left);
    final TableLayout table_center = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table_center);
    final Button Buton_left = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Buton_left);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    table_left.setOnClickListener(this);
    table_center.setOnClickListener(this);
    Buton_left.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

    int targetId = v.getId();
    if(targetId == R.id.Buton_left)
    {

        if(table_center.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
        {
            table_center.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

If the problem is still there, pls post your manifest.

Comment: It says the table_center is not defined. Does it not get defined when you use table_center.setOnClickListener(this)?

Comment: Making it a global variable. Thanks for the help, I will test this.

Comment: The App stop working completely if you put make those variables as final and global

Comment: android error opening trace file no such file or directory (2)

Comment: If I put those references in the onClick method and right below setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); then it works but I feel like that is really inefficient

Comment: That's totally a different question, your api level and the version of emulator don't match. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2. Your API level and the sdk version don't match.