# android application error 5

Tags: java, android, eclipse, error-handling, eclipse-plugin

I try to implement an application based on rscm (middleware). When I try to run on emulator, I get the errors listed below:

> Error :03-27 16:58:20.490: E/Trace(1508): error opening trace file: No
>   such file or directory (2)
>
> 03-27 21:53:21.610: D/AndroidRuntime(3803): Shutting down VM 03-27
>   21:53:21.610: W/dalvikvm(3803): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 03-27 21:53:21.760:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-27 21:53:21.760:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.context_application/com.example.context_application.MyContextAwareActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.example.context_application.MyContextAwareActivity" on path:
>   /data/app/com.example.context_application-2.apk 03-27 21:53:21.760:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
>   03-27 21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   03-27 21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 03-27
>   21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   03-27 21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 03-27
>   21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 03-27 21:53:21.760:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 03-27
>   21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-27
>   21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 03-27 21:53:21.760:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   03-27 21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 03-27
>   21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-27 21:53:21.760:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3803): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class
>   "com.example.context_application.MyContextAwareActivity" on path:
>   /data/app/com.example.context_application-2.apk 03-27 21:53:21.760:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>   03-27 21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) 03-27
>   21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) 03-27
>   21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
>   03-27 21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
>   03-27 21:53:21.760: E/AndroidRuntime(3803):   ... 11 more

Can anyone help?

```
package com.example.context;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.aspectsense.rscm.ContextValue;
import org.aspectsense.rscm.context.client.ContextListenerActivity;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.Date;

public class MyContextAwareActivity extends ContextListenerActivity
{
    @Override public String[] getRequestedScopes()
    {
        return new String[] { "battery.level" };
    }

    private TextView messageTextView;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        messageTextView = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(messageTextView);
        appendMessage("Activity created");
    }

    private void appendMessage(final String message)
    {
        final String currentMessage = messageTextView.getText().toString();
        messageTextView.setText(currentMessage + "\n" + message);
    }

    @Override public void onContextValueChanged(ContextValue contextValue)
    {
       try
        {
            appendMessage(new Date() + ": The battery level is " +         contextValue.getValueAsInteger() + "%");
        }
        catch (JSONException jsone)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error while displaying context event: " + contextValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}










<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.context"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.context.MyContextAwareActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: plz add full logcat result with question to get more help .

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to write to external storage. Have you set up an SD card in eclipse?

Do any of these answers help? [error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2)

Comment: yes i have already setuo i am wondering if the layout.xml or main .xml can play a role for this error???

Comment: Can you post the full error log or more of the stack trace? It sounds like the error might be in the code rather than the setup of the logging.

Comment: It failed because it did not find class com.example.context_application.MyContextAwareActivity. In your code the package is named com.example.context with no _application. Somewhere you need to fix the package reference.