# LogCat error Error opening trace file: no such file or directory

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Sorry if this is a very noob question, but the code below is not giving an output and I the logcat view isn't clear so I can't tell how far it is getting when I run the emulator.

Have I got the radio buttons coded correctly?
Are the variable statements coded correctly?
Can you see any other errors?

Layout xml is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="@string/pressu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="@string/volu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/molu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/tempu"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/calc" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginRight="33dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/pressure" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/vol" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/mol" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/temp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Java for the main activity is here

```
package com.minichanic.idealgas;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText pressure;
    private EditText volume;
    private EditText moles;
    private EditText temperature;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            pressure = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            volume = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            moles = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            temperature= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
       }

            public void onClick(View view) { 
                //set values to the input

                float pressuren = Float.parseFloat(pressure.getText().toString());
                float volumen = Float.parseFloat(volume.getText().toString());
                float molesn = Float.parseFloat(moles.getText().toString());
                float temperaturen = Float.parseFloat(temperature.getText().toString());

                //change values to standard conditions if blank
                if (pressuren == 0) {pressuren = 100000;
                             }
                if (volumen == 0) {volumen = (float)0.0247;
                             }
                if (molesn == 0) {molesn= 1;
                             }
                if (temperaturen == 0) {temperaturen = 298;
                            }

         //set input values as answers for set text later
                float pressans = (float) pressuren;
                float volans = (float) volumen;
                float moleans = (float) molesn;
                float temperaturans = (float) temperaturen;   

                //set calculation depending on radio button
                switch (view.getId()) { 
            case R.id.radio0:
                pressans = (float) (molesn * 8.31 * temperaturen ) / volumen;
                 break;
            case R.id.radio1:
                volans = (float) (molesn * 8.31 * temperaturen ) / pressuren;
                 break;
             case R.id.radio2:
                 moleans = (float) ((float) (pressuren * volumen)/(8.31 * temperaturen));
                    break;
             case R.id.radio3:
                 temperaturans = (float) ((float) (pressuren * volumen)/(8.31 * molesn));
                        break;          
                  }

          //print values in the EditText fields
           pressure.setText(""+pressans);
           volume.setText(""+volans);
           moles.setText(""+moleans);
           temperature.setText(""+temperaturans);

            }


     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
     }

}
```

The logCat i am getting for the package is:

Error opening trace file: no such file or directory

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2)

Comment: Please next time do a search before asking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a system level error log and it does not affect execution of your application, so you don't have to worry about it.

Generally Its occurs `Jelly Bean (android 4.1)`.And mainly its because of some SD-card issue.

Comment: I did do a search before asking, but I didn't understand it.  The app doesn't work in the emulator- I haven't tried it on my Nexus yet.