# LogCat error: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: android, logcat, trace, android-logcat

I've got a totally new Android project in Eclipse, one activity with one simple textview, black background, nothing else. I didn't modify anything except adding some permissions in order to listen few advices on the Internet.

Of course there are some threads about this problem, but mostly they are marked as a duplicate of [error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2). But the solution in that thread is "reinstall everything" - this is not a good answer for me. I want to know what is wrong and what to do to repair it.
Please help me get an answer with which I'll really understand what is wrong here.
As I've said, it's a new Eclipse project, but if you'll need some code, just write a comment please.
Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:

My Manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.yellowjello.sejmipolitika"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >


            <activity
                android:name=".Main"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

My java:

```
    package com.yellowjello.sejmipolitika;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class Main extends Activity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
```

My xml code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <!--
         The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc.
    -->

    <!--
         This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows.
    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Nothing more there. It's clean.

Comment: This message is entirely spurious.  You need to look at the following lines in the logcat to find out why your program is crashing, and fix that.  When you do, you will stop getting this message - at least, you will no longer get it from *your* program, though you may still get it from other programs on the device, possibly including buggy factory apps.