# Console error "error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)" in Android monitor when running on actual device

Tags: android, cordova

My main question is: what does this error mean? Should I worry about it? Should I ignore it?

Secondarily, what is the cause of this error and how might I fix it? I have certainly seen this question: [error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2) , but "reinstall everything" is a rather blunt solution. And in cases where you, unfortunately, are inheriting a project that doesn't have clear from-scratch installation steps, may not be feasible.

Is this a generic error that could indicate any number of missing files, or is it talking about a very specific "trace file" in a well known location?

Other info: I'm running on a Galaxy S2, the Tag is "Trace", and it is the very first log that is written for the application. Looking at all messages, it seems mine is not the only application logging this error. I get the feeling it is a false alarm of some kind.

Answer (score 6):

The error message comes from the [systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html) code.  It indicates that your device doesn't support systrace tracing.  You can ignore it.

Comment: That is super helpful information! It would be nice if you could point me to somewhere specific to verify that fact.

Comment: Log message is generated on line 172 of https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/jb-mr2-release/libcutils/trace.c .