# App can't be opened with the error in opening trace file

Tags: android

I installed my application and the application is running well already.
But after sometime, the app can't be opened and the error is "error opening trace file: No such file or directory". What could be the problem?
I installed the same app to Samsung Note2 with Android version 4.1.2. I don't have any problem.
I installed to another device with Android version 4.1.1, and that device has problem.
My LogCat message is as shown below.

```
10-07 20:51:50.910: W/System.err(19785): Invalid int: ""
10-07 20:51:51.140: W/dalvikvm(19785): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e97438)
10-07 20:52:09.510: E/Trace(19817): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-07 20:52:09.530: W/dalvikvm(19817): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
10-07 20:52:09.750: W/System.err(19817): Invalid int: ""
10-07 20:52:09.910: I/Adreno200-EGL(19817): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_Merge_release_AU (Merge)
10-07 20:52:09.910: I/Adreno200-EGL(19817): Build Date: 10/26/12 Fri
10-07 20:52:09.910: I/Adreno200-EGL(19817): Local Branch: 
10-07 20:52:09.910: I/Adreno200-EGL(19817): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
10-07 20:52:09.910: I/Adreno200-EGL(19817): Local Patches: NONE
10-07 20:52:09.910: I/Adreno200-EGL(19817): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.01.21.010 +  NOTHING
10-07 20:52:09.970: W/dalvikvm(19817): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e97438)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "error opening trace file" message is a [red herring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521737/console-error-error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2-in-andro/18522189#18522189) -- it just means your device doesn't support systrace.

The "Invalid int" message might have something to do with the problem, but really what's happening is something is throwing an exception that isn't caught.

Normally when a thread exits with an uncaught exception you get to see the exception in the log, but something seems to be preventing that here.  If you run the app in the debugger, and set an exception breakpoint on all uncaught exceptions, you should be able to see where it's coming from.  (Alternatively, try to track down the source of the "Invalid int" message and put a breakpoint there.)

Comment: Yeah sometimes it is hard to debug. I found the problem as I am accessing the object without initialization. But from the LogCat, it is not that obvious.