# Error opening trace file on phone

Tags: android

I get the following error in LogCat. I want to show the stacktrace when the app crashes on my phone. The emulator does show a stacktrace, but my phone doesn't. 
What can I do?

```
01-29 11:09:58.490: E/Trace(10692): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-29 11:09:58.560: W/dalvikvm(10692): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
01-29 11:09:59.200: W/dalvikvm(10692): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e56438)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225602/app-cant-be-opened-with-the-error-in-opening-trace-file

Comment: How would I be able to get a stracktrace on my device?