# Android E/Trace(627): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-logcat

my LogCat appear some error...

```
E/Trace(627): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

and then i can't find solution help me please.
ps. i'm trying to set my avd sd card space 256MB, but it's too same error

**-----------------My LogCat-----------------**

```
06-24 02:31:13.450: E / Trace(627):  error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-24 02:31:14.290: D / libEGL(627): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
06-24 02:31:14.300: D / (627):       HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established     0x2a08fd48, tid 627
06-24 02:31:14.310: D / libEGL(627): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
06-24 02:31:14.320: D / libEGL(627): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
06-24 02:31:14.390: W / EGL_emulation(627):     eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-24 02:31:14.400: D / OpenGLRenderer(627):    Enabling debug mode 0
```

**-----------------My Source Code-----------------**

```
package com.nathaniel.web_list_20113212_nathaniel;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Web_List_Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    DBManager dbmgr;
    SQLiteDatabase sdb;
    Cursor cur;
    int list_count;

    LinearLayout layout_weblist;
    Button prev_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_list);

        layout_weblist = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.weblist_area);

        dbmgr = new DBManager(this);
        sdb = dbmgr.getReadableDatabase();
        cur = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Websites", null);
        list_count = cur.getCount();

        if(list_count < 1) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("등록된 웹사이트가 존재하지 않습니다.");
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setTextSize(20);
            layout_weblist.addView(tv);
        }
        else if(list_count > 1) {
            cur.moveToNext();

            LinearLayout layout_webcontent = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout_webcontent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            layout_webcontent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BBDEF8"));

            /* <Column Line>
             * wid integer
             * wname text 
             * waddress text 
             * remark text 
             * hits integer */
            String[] column = {String.valueOf(cur.getInt(0)), cur.getString(1), cur.getString(2), cur.getString(3), String.valueOf(cur.getInt(4))};
            TextView[] tv_content = new TextView[5];

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                tv_content[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv_content[i].setText(column[i]);

                layout_webcontent.addView(tv_content[i]);
                layout_webcontent.setId(i);
                layout_webcontent.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            layout_weblist.addView(layout_webcontent);
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "null" })
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater html_layer;
        View html_view = null;

        if(v.getId() != list_count) {
            html_layer = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            html_view = html_layer.inflate(R.layout.web_html, null);
            this.addContentView(html_view, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            cur.moveToPosition(v.getId());

            String waddr = cur.getString(2);        // address
            TextView tv_html = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.htmlview);

            URL url = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedInputStream buf = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(waddr);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                buf = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(buf, "utf-8"));

                String line = null;
                String page = "";

                while((line = bufreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    page += line;
                }

            tv_html.setText(page);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.i("############", e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        else
            ((ViewManager)html_view.getParent()).removeView(html_view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The error message comes from the systrace code. It indicates that your device doesn't support systrace tracing. You can ignore it.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521737/console-error-error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2-in-andro/18522189#18522189)