# Android: Get Atomic Time

Tags: java, android, time, atomic

I'm trying to get the atomic time for an Android app. I'm using http://hi-android.info/src/android/net/SntpClient.java.html as NTP client and the following code to implement the NTP (= sample code from SntpClient.java):

```
SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
if (client.requestTime("time.foo.com")) {
    long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - client.getNtpTimeReference();
}
```

I tried different server from this list: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/timesources.html, but the "client.requestTime("SERVER")" is always "false" ...

My code:

```
SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
if (client.requestTime("hera.limescope.net", 10000)) {
    long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - client.getNtpTimeReference();
    textAtomicClock.setText(String.valueOf(now));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Freddi

Comment: You said you tried several server, but as a note the one you have above does not have a correctly configured DNS. Try `0.debian.pool.ntp.org` and you should get a working one.

Comment: That's just an example. I'm located in Germany so I tried every DE Server listed ...

Comment: I just tried a random number (not that many) from the list and none answered on port 123. Anyway, it was just a comment. :)

Comment: I now tried `client.requestTime("0.debian.pool.ntp.org", 1000000)`, too. Didn't work. Perhaps it's a permission problem? Does a socket connection need a permission in my Manifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, you need permission to access internet. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.

Comment: You should add logging to the `SntpClient` and check `logcat` what exceptions you get.

Comment: I already had an INTERNET permission ... maybe I need a special one for a socket connection?! I also checked the logcat and got this: `09-04 20:29:09.014: E/Trace(16328): error opening trace file: No such file or directory` ...

Comment: Maybe it's an sdk problem. I use `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />` and I can't find any sdk requirements listed in the SntpClient.java ...

Comment: Check this for `error opening....` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2

Comment: Changed nothing, it's still not working :( maybe the mistake is somewhere else ... so I uploaded my code: [link](http://www.xup.in/dl,50306143/Dashboard_2013-09-08.zip/) maybe somebody will have a look ...

Comment: One thing came to my mind that I assume you already checked, but do you run this in the emulator? Have you verified that the emulator have Internat access?

Comment: The app is tested on a tablet, which has a working wifi connection. I also tested, if the app really has an internet connection.

Comment: Found my mistake! I did know that I had to process the ntp task in the background ... I solved the problem with Androids AsyncTask function. Thanks to all who helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my mistake! I didn't know that I had to process the ntp task in the background ... I solved the problem with Androids AsyncTask function. Thanks to all who helped me!