# Developing Application with audio playback dor Android

Tags: android, audio, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, playback

I want to play a sound in an Android app by clicking a Button. But in the emulator the app quites immediately after starting.

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound_file_1);
    ......

    public void playsound(View view){

       mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
       if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() ){
           mediaPlayer.pause();
       }
       else{
           mediaPlayer.start();
       }
}
```

This is the function which is called by this button in the layout-xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
                style="?buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick = "playsound"
                android:text="@string/dummy_button" />
```

I'm worring the file could not be found, but i don't know why.
It is in the folder "*projectname*/src/main/res/raw/sound_file_1"
First, the file had the ending ".mp3", but i deleted it as I thought this could help.

In the device logcat, there is an error message, which says:

```
09-21 00:00:58.044    2075-2075/com.example.projectname E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2

Comment: THANKS a lot!! It worked! I was looking for the solution the whole day...