# E/Trace ( 2994): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: android, xml

im trying to port a system app ( keybord ) from ics ( stock ) to jb ( cyanogenmod ) to support the physical keyboard of the phone , but after installation with necessary files it force close when trying to type on it , with the [E/Trace   ( 2994): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)] error in the logcat , even though i can access its preference menu and enable / disable things with no problem , need help I'm new to these things
AndroidManifest.xml :

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.permission.CUSTOMIZATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW" />

<application android:label="@string/textinput_strings_application_name_txt" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

    <uses-library android:name="com.sonyericsson.uxpres" />

    <service android:label="@string/textinput_strings_application_name_txt" android:name=".glue.InputMethodServiceGlue" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />

        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method" />

    </service>

    <service android:label="test service" android:name=".test.TestService" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp.test.ITestService" />

        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <activity android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme" android:label="@string/textinput_strings_application_name_txt" android:name=".SettingsActivity" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">

        <intent-filter>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme" android:label="@string/textinput_strings_settings_language" android:name=".controller.settings.LanguageSelectActivity" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />

    <activity android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme" android:label="@string/textinput_strings_settings_quick_text" android:name=".controller.settings.PredictionOptionsActivity" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />

</application>

<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" />
```

`

Comment: See the comments on this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2