# Trying to send sms programatically but it's throwning an null pointer exception

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, nullpointerexception, smsmanager

I am Trying to loop  through a list of numbers and send them a message but somehow  my code is throwing a null pointer exception  and i can't figure out where is the problem.

here the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MSGHandler {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    public BroadcastReceiver smsDeliveredReceiver,smsSentReceiver;


public MSGHandler(Context c,List<String> Name,List<String> Number,String Message)
{
    int Limit = Name.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < Limit;i++)
    {
        if(Number.get(i).length() > 0)
        {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
             PendingIntent piSent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
                PendingIntent piDelivered=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED),0);

                //---when the SMS has been sent---
                smsSentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:

                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:

                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };

                //---when the SMS has been delivered---
                smsDeliveredReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        switch (getResultCode())
                        {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                                break;
                            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:

                                break;                        
                        }
                    }
                };
                c.registerReceiver(smsSentReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
                c.registerReceiver(smsDeliveredReceiver, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));
                sms.sendTextMessage(Number.get(i), null, Name.get(i)+Message, piSent, piDelivered);  

        }
    }
}
}
```

I am  Calling this classes in an activity on a button click. Like this

```
Dialog Alert = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            try
            {
                MSGHandler sms = new MSGHandler(MainActivity.this,DBHandler.Contacts_Name_List,DBHandler.Contacts_Number_List,"HII!!!!");
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Alert.setTitle(e.toString());
            }
            Alert.show();
```

I am Using Eclipse and using my device as an emulator

here's log

```
 error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

  loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so

 loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so

 loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
  Enabling debug mode 0
```

(When the exception is thrown in the app .. log displays nothing )

Here are the ADb logs after i try to send the msg and the exception is thrown

[image]

Any Solutions?

Comment: Post the LogCat please.

Comment: @MiguelMaciel i am not sure how to do that as i am  testing it on my device

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Eclipse? IntelliJ? Android Studio?

Comment: @CarlAnderson Eclipse

Comment: Window > Show View > Other > LogCat

Comment: @Guardanis  error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
 Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: @MiguelMaciel  error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
 loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
 Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: @user2801966 Try connecting your device to your computer, check logcat for any messages to see if device is connected, when connected do your operation, then post the logs from logcat here. Other wise the probability of getting a good answer is pretty low

Comment: @aravind I am doing that only  , when i  run my program in eclipse it directly runs on my android device and all the log entries i have already posted ... when the app throws the exception the log doesn't add any entry however when i close my app on my device this entry add on the log "showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection" which shows that my device is  connected to the pc

Comment: ok, forget eclipse. Can you open adb logcat from your command line. You would need to open terminal, go to android-sdk_folder/platform-tools. Run `adb logcat`

Comment: @aravind Okie  Aravind i edited the question and pasted the image of the log etries

Comment: Thanks. But one issue, can't see the exception! Check this image http://adrianvintu.com/blogengine/image.axd?picture=Colored+Logcat+Script+for+Windows+-+before+color.png. This is an example of an exception(Java) is thrown in adb if you let it crash

Comment: @aravind Done pasted the new log report .. not sure but i don't think i found any exception entry in the log

Comment: Sorry but still insufficient. You might be having this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446049/error-opening-trace-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2. If not that, at least delete and create the virtual device, restart eclipse, adb kill-server, and try.. Without the error trace, cannot be of much help, sorry.

Comment: @aravind Okie No problem .. but still thumbs up  for the  help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a nice sleep helped me alot  and i found out that the exception was being thrown because i was trying to message on a blank number i.e " " a space

and the solution was using

```
 if(Number.get(i).trim().length() > 0)
```

instead of

```
 if(Number.get(i).length() > 0)
```